# Can I dynamically link without giving read permission to the libraries?

Tags: c++, linux

I have some dynamically linked libraries that I would like to protect from unauthorized users. I cannot use groups / ACLs to do this. I have a list of the licensed users and can get a yes/no at runtime as to whether a given uid is authorized. Linux and GCC/Clang, if it matters.

Comment: This appears to be a question about file permission on Linux, not about software development. I would recommend you to ask this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Philipp, I specifically can't use file permissions to solve my problem, I think there has to be some linker magic to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

It takes a bit of extra work but it's doable and would still be considered dynamic:

1. Make your main program setuid-root (or grant the CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE capability to your program -- see `capabilities(7)`)
2. When your program is executed, do your runtime authorization check
3. If the user is authorized, use `dlopen` (along with the root/DAC_OVERRIDE) to load the libraries. You would then need to use `dlsym` to find/resolve the symbols you need from the library.
4. Drop the capability and/or revert UID for best security.

(All that being said, using a group ID is much simpler. You can simply grant group membership to those users who are considered authorized.)